# Spring MVC file not found exception when creating bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I have the following directory structure:

[image]

I am creating a bean the following way:

```
@Configuration
public class Create {
public static String path = new File("src/main/webapp/resources/nodes.txt").getAbsolutePath();
@Bean
public static Graph returnGraph() throws IOException {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
[rest of the code]
    return graph;
}
}
```

I want to read the file nodes.txt located in DeployedResources/webapp/resources

However I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException. Now this works if I specify the absolute path if my file is located in Desktop for example. But I cannot do this as then it wont work on another machine.

I am trying to specify a relative path, so it will work on all machines,but when I run it as a Spring MVC application, the working directory changes. What can I do so the file can be read from any machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this path:

```
 new File("src/main/webapp/resources/nodes.txt").getAbsolutePath();
```

With removing `getAbsolutePath()`:

```
  new File("src/main/webapp/resources/nodes.txt");
```

Comment: Better yet, get it from the CLASSPATH.  File path is meaningless when it's inside a WAR.

Comment: `C:\Users\Na\Downloads\eclipse-jee-mars-1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\src\main\webapp\resources\nodes.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)` This is the error i get,  everything from src onwards does not exist.

Comment: Try to refresh your project and synchronize with repository @user3809938

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Na\Downloads\eclipse-jee-mars-1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\resources\nodes.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)` this time i get this error

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\nodes.txt (The system cannot find the path specified`, this is the new error.